# archive todos from org agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I make a function that move from `TODO` state to `DONE` and archive it in the archives files, and I set `org-mode-map` to make this function by a keybinding, but in agenda it doesn't change the `TODO` state. I tried to find a `org-agenda-mode-map` or something similar but I can't find it. My function is:

```
(defun mark-done-and-archive ()
   (interactive)
   (org-todo 'done)
   (org-archive-subtree))
 (define-key org-mode-map "\C-c\C-x\C-s" 'mark-done-and-archive)
```

## EDIT

So when in my `TODOS.org` file I hit `C-c C-x C-s` the todo automatically is marked as `DONE` and move from `TODOS.org` to `archive.org` but when I make this in org-agenda buffer the todo is moved from his file well, the only problem is that it isn't marked as done. As example:

### Archive todos.org

`* TODO one todo from todo.org
 * TODO Another todo`

So I open `todos.org` and complete the first todo so I hit `C-c C-x C-s` and the file `todos.org` now contains:

`* TODO Another todo`

and `archive.org` contains:
`DONE one todo from todo.org`

But when I show my org-agenda and `* TODO Another todo` it's show, I try to complete and move to my archive file, again with `C-c C-x C-s` but I obtain the following in archive.org:

`* DONE one todo from todo.org
 * TODO Another todo`

and `todos.org` it's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org-mode` maintains two sets of functions for most things.  The 'normal' version (like `org-todo`) and the agenda version (`org-agenda-todo`).  If you rewrite your function to use the agenda version, all will be well:

```
(defun agenda-mark-done-and-archive ()
   (interactive)
   (org-agenda-todo 'done)
   (org-agenda-archive))
 (define-key org-agenda-mode-map "\C-c\C-x\C-s" 'agenda-mark-done-and-archive)
```

Internally, `org-agenda-archive` works by calling `org-archive-subtree`.  So if we use [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) we can modify `org-archive-subtree` to first mark things as done and then do whatever it normally does:

```
(defun org-archive-done (&optional arg)
  (org-todo 'done))

(advice-add 'org-archive-subtree :before 'org-archive-done)
```

This version changes the normal and agenda versions simultaneously.

Note that the help for `org-archive-subtree` says

> The tree will be moved to that location, the subtree
>   heading be marked DONE, and the current time will be added.

So this should already be happening.  If it isn't, there may be some other issue.

Comment: Hy again, your solution works well bu after I upgrade emacs and org-mode org-agenda-mode-map is void, and I cant find another equivalent var, any help??

Comment: @rafaelleru You may need to `(require 'org-agenda)` first to get the map to exist.